# preg_match start with specific word then anything after

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I am trying to filter some results so that then results shown must start with a specific word "`skin_`", then can contain any characters after it.

So far I have the following:

```
preg_match('/^skin_/s', $file)
```

But I'm not sure this will allow any character after the specific word.

Could someone let me know if this is correct else help to ensure any characters are allowed?

Comment: Did you try it? Looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: @Cfreak - yes, it works fine, the results display, however I just need to know that it will allow any character after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing regex is correct. All it tries to check is if `$file` begins with the string `skin_` which effectively means it could be followed by anything.